# How to insert default value if value is Null in insert method of stored procedure in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**My thought**
I want to insert default value if value supplied is Null in Insert method of Stored procedure.Lets say i want to insert default value for the column Lastname if value supplied is null

**My SP**

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Any]   

  @ID int=0,
  @Name = varchar(max),
  @Lastname = varchar(max),

AS  
BEGIN   
  
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
BEGIN TRAN  
 BEGIN TRY    
   BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO dbo.ABC
    ( ID, 
      Name,
      Address)

 Values
     (
  @ID, 
  @Name,
  @Lastname)
```

**code that i tried**
I tried using this code shows there is error in case statement

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ABC
    ( ID, 
      Name,
     case when Address = NULL then 'N/A' else
      Address)
```

Comment: Must be: ...CASE WHEN Address IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE
      Address END)

Comment: shows error in case statement. Error shows expecting ID,Pseudocode or quotedID

Comment: I just explained the correct syntax for your CASE WHEN construct. You have further issues like after "INSERT INTO ABC" must appear either a select or VALUES...

Comment: above SP is used for Saving data. It works before i use case statement. I just want to set default value. Any changes should i make to the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could phrase your insert as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.ABC (ID, Name, Address)
SELECT ID, Name, COALESCE(Address, 'N/A');
```

Or, you could also give the `Address` column a default value of `N/A` in your table definition.

Comment: I'm new to SQL , My SP is used for Saving "Post Method"  can we use select statement here